# Shared library symbol lookup template instantiation

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, ros2

I'm using a shared library utility that looks up symbols from a shared library (on non-windows platforms using `GetProcAddress`).
This works for normal functions.
However, I need a function that is a template instantiation in a namespace.
I have confirmed using `nm -gDC lib.so` that the library contains the symbol and spelled it exactly the same in my lookup attempt but it can't be found.
`nm -gDC lib.so`

```
...
0000000000009575 T rosidl_service_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_service_type_support_handle<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts>()
...
```

I've tried to look up:

```
GetProcAddress((HINSTANCE)(lib), "rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_service_type_support_handle<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts>");
```

but it returns a `nullptr`.
Is there some special handling for template instantiations that I couldn't find?
I've found a different method that returns me what I need but I'd still be interested in any resources on why that didn't work!

Comment: Remove `-C` option. You want mangled name, that's the name `GetProcAddress` expects.

Comment: Ah, thank you that makes sense. The name mangling depends on the compiler, though, right?
So this wouldn't be compiler portable let alone platform-independent.

Comment: You can't expect a platform-independent binary; that `lib.so` certainly won't work on Windows, or Mac, or Android phone. And yes, name mangling schemes are often compiler-specific; if you want somewhat portable names exported from your library, stick to plain C functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have confirmed using nm -gDC lib.so that the library contains the symbol and spelled it exactly the same in my lookup attempt but it can't be found.

As Igor Tandetnik correctly commented, the name the library *actually* exports is the `C++` *mangled* name, and *not* `rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_service_type_support_handle<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts>` (which is the *demangled* name).

To see the *actual* symbol name, use `nm -D lib.so` (in particular, omit the `-C` flag).